# ZIP files not working in SSIS (server level issue?)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, zip

I'm posting this rather odd issue here in the remote chance that someone has come across this before, or possibly just has an idea or two about what I could try or check next because I'm stumped.

**Summary**: SQL 2008 SSIS package tasks that attempt to create files with .zip extension fail with

> "Access to the path is denied"

**Detail**: This first occurred in a test environment with a package that works fine in Dev (and Prod). The part that makes this problem odd is that it is all about the File Extension, not security. I mention this now to curb replies about checking the security (SSIS Account, Directory Level permissions etc.) :- it's not that, 100%.

So, I've built an SSIS package as a proof of behavior, that takes 3 files (`a.txt, b.txt, c.txt`) and respectively for

(a) uses `CozyRoc Zip` to Create a Zip,

(b) uses a script task to create a `.zip` (using `GZipStream` - I know this creates a GZIP not a ZIP but bear with me...) and

(c) native SSIS File System Task copies the file from `c.txt` to `c.zip` (yes, creating a `.zip` file that is not really a zip file).

All Three fail with the above message - the `.ZIP` files are created for (a) and (b), but remain at 0 length. (For (c) just the error message).

Now, I edit the SSIS package and change the extensions of the destinations (to `.ZOP` or `.ZIP2` or `.GZ` or `.ANYTHING`), and all 3 work perfectly. And this is obviously how I know that it's the `.ZIP` extension not a "normal" security issue.

So I've initially assumed this is a one-off on this test server because it was the only place it happens, but I've found another box (build rehearsal) on which exactly the same problem exists. I've tried associating `.ZIP` with various different programs (Windows Explorer, WinZip, 7Zip, WinRar & "no program") and nothing works, and I've googled the problem to death with no luck yet.

I've tried creating `.ZIP` files with the various installed archive programs using their GUIs and they all work fine. Existing `.ZIP` files can be unzipped using `CozyRoc`. Existing `.GZ` (GZIP) files renamed to `.ZIP` can be unzipped using the script GZipStream decompress. And I can rename files to and from `.ZIP` using SSIS or Explorer/CMD. It's just SSIS (specifically SSIS) creating a file with extension .ZIP (specifically .ZIP) throws this error.

I'm starting to suspect it might have something to do with SSIS thinking that .ZIP is an archive "folder" not a ".ZIP File" but I don't know where to go with this idea, proving it or fixing it.

Any ideas at all? - at my wits end!!

Thanks in advance

**P.S.** The "obvious" answer of using `.ZIP2` and renaming is not an option, there are (literally) hundreds of packages running in production that create `.ZIP` files and packages need to move from Test to Prod without modification. I really need a solution, not a workaround, in this instance if there is one.

Comment: Create a new, empty SSIS package. Add an Execute Process Task as shown [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/njY6N.png) Make `C:\ssisdata\test.zip` some valid path on your server that exists, preferably with no spaces in the path. Deploy and run the package on the server. Same issue?

Comment: @billinkc Good idea, bear with me...

Comment: I don't doubt the sincerity with which you've laid out your issue, I only wish more folks on here would go through these lengths to figure something out. What I can say from my perspective is that I can't recreate your issue. This smells like a virus scanner on the server keep you safe from nasty compressed archives. Or maybe some banjanxed security/gpo that only exists on that class of box and doesn't apply to dev/prod. Something else to test is whether it's all accounts (SQL Agent vs an ordinary user). Perhaps there's something odd about the account that's performing the task.

Comment: @billinkc, yes that works.  And no surprise regarding re-creating the issue - I've never seen this before at any previous place of employment, and as I say it only occurs on 2 servers (out of 4 I've tried and many more where similar packages are happily zipping things - it's a fairly big company!)  Good suggestion re virus checker - I'll check that idea out too, thank you.

Comment: @billinkc Found a third server it's happening on.  All three have McAfee in common, this turned out to be a false lead - however I have some further ideas based on your suggestions so thanks again.

Comment: Good to hear. Once you get this figured out, post it as an answer in case anyone else runs into this.

Comment: Can you use [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to verify what happens when you create those zip files? Beware that the captured file could be big and with lots of events. Play a bit with filtering before monitoring your folder/process. Try to see if the File(create/write/close) events of your zip have a SUCCESS status (like [here](http://screencast.com/t/mj2pZlE1c7V2)) or there's anything else happening in the log.

Comment: @bilinkc no joy yet but if/when I find the answer I'll definitely report.

Comment: @Marian This is a good idea; I have tried to use procmon before for a different issue and found it very hard work to interpret the results.  However, since (almost) all else has failed... thanks for the idea and I'll post back.

Comment: Yeah, it's cumbersome to use at best. And it generates loads of data to look onto. But it's still a brilliant tool and can help shed some light. In case you need, this is a [reminder](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor) on how to use it better.

Comment: @Marian  Eventually solved it using procmon, surprisingly quickly! (I could grow to like procmon after all :))  There's a redgate compression tool used on non-production servers (hyperbac) which was showing share violations against the .ZIP file paths - killed the service, problem goes away.  Now, I would like to give credit since it was your and bilinkc's suggestions that solved it, but I don't know the protocol here - am I allowed to suggest that you post it as an answer and I'll upvote it or something?  Or should I just post my own answer?

Comment: Marian needs the SO rep more than me ;)

Comment: Ha! It's great that you solved it. Worked with Hyperbac in the past (before Redgate) and really liked it. Didn't know it causes these issues. Just make sure that McAffee isn't scanning any of the SQL Server's files or processes. The most that I hate on a db server is a defrag tool or an antivirus :-).
@billinkc I just told him to use a hammer, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a RedGate tool (HyperBac) having a file association with .ZIP extension files (amongst others).  Hyperbac's monitoring of .ZIP files appears to have clashed with SSIS's attempt to write to the .ZIP file, as procmon reported shared file access violations, causing a spurious ACCESS DENIED error to be reported by the package.

Since use of the tool is necessary on our environments, I was able to solve the problem by deleting the .ZIP association using the GUI ("Hyperbac Configuration Manager" > "Extensions" > Ext=.ZIP, Delete)